# LibGDX 1.5, how to stretch to fit width

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, viewport

I have started looking into libGDX in the past few days, I was able to setup the project and draw some sprites using the SpriteBatch, but now I am stuck.

I have some sprites drawn on the screen, which are all inside a 64x64 pixel wide box and I would like to stretch them to fit the screen size so that the aspect ratio is preserved. I think I should use a Viewport, but I don't really understand how to use it. My code so far is as follows:

```
@Override
public void create () {

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(64, 64, cam);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    ballTex = new Texture("Ball.png");
    balls = new Ball[6];

    balls[0] = new Ball(64 / 2 - BALLSIZE / 2, 64 - BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE);
    balls[1] = new Ball(64 - BALLSIZE, 4 * 64 / 5 - BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE);
    balls[2] = new Ball(64 - BALLSIZE, 64 / 5, BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE);
    balls[3] = new Ball(64 / 2 - BALLSIZE / 2, 0, BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE);
    balls[4] = new Ball(0, 64 / 5, BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE);
    balls[5] = new Ball(0, 4 * 64 / 5 - BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE, BALLSIZE);

    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
}

@Override
public void render () {

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "touched on coordinates " + Gdx.input.getX() + ", " + Gdx.input.getY());
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "ball size: " + balls[0].getX());
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.setColor(Color.RED);
    batch.draw(ballTex, balls[0].getX(), balls[0].getY(), balls[0].getWidth(), balls[0].getHeight());
    batch.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    batch.draw(ballTex, balls[1].getX(), balls[1].getY(), balls[1].getWidth(), balls[1].getHeight());
    batch.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    batch.draw(ballTex, balls[2].getX(), balls[2].getY(), balls[2].getWidth(), balls[2].getHeight());
    batch.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    batch.draw(ballTex, balls[3].getX(), balls[3].getY(), balls[3].getWidth(), balls[3].getHeight());
    batch.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    batch.draw(ballTex, balls[4].getX(), balls[4].getY(), balls[4].getWidth(), balls[4].getHeight());
    batch.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    batch.draw(ballTex, balls[5].getX(), balls[5].getY(), balls[5].getWidth(), balls[5].getHeight());
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

When I run it with a resolution different than 64x64, sprites aren't stretched, but they stay at the same original size, while if I start from a 64x64 resolution and resize it later, the behaviour is as expected, as you can see in these pictures (first one is with desktop size of 128x256, second one is with desktop size of 64x64 and last one is 64x64 stretched, which has the behaviour I want):

[image: Running with desktop size of 128x256]

[image: Running with desktop size of 64x64]

[image: Running with desktop size of 64x64 and then resized]

Also, I find the information about libGDX being a bit confusing, probably due to the differences among versions. If you could show me some good tutorials about the latest version I am using (1.5), especially about camera, screen, viewport, which I can't fully understand yet, I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you are not using `Game` and `Screen`, `resize(...)` is probably not called in your scenario, only if you do it manually. Add a `resize(Gdx.graphics.getScreenWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getScreenHeight())` at the end of your `create()`method. Furthermore, you have to set the projection matrix, just like Lucien wrote in his answer.

Comment: I had to add those two lines plus these:

`cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2f, cam.viewportHeight / 2f, 0)` and
`cam.update()`.

Now it seems to work properly

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not using your viewport when rendering the sprites.
You should set the camera used by the SpriteBatch in your `create` method with

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```